# How to understand "or so it seemed to Harry" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, phrase-structure

> Seconds later, **or so it seemed to Harry**, he was woken by what sounded like cannon-fire as the door burst open.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sub>

I'm not quite sure how to understand "or so it seemed to Harry". Should it be "[or] [so it seemed to Harry]" or "[or so] [it seemed to Harry]"? Is it a common expression? Are there other ways to express it?

Comment: This is a common idiom. You can find a [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20it%20seems) with a simple google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seconds later, or [**so it seemed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20it%20seems) to Harry...

is equivalent to:

> Seconds later, according to Harry's perceptions...

or:

> It seemed to Harry that seconds later...

Comment: What about the sense of 'or'?

Comment: The sense of "or: Either it was only a few seconds, **or** it was Harry's illusion that it was only a few seconds.